# c++ for loop increase dual points

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, for-loop

This is my first C++ related question here on StackOverflow

I have a vector of previously initialized 3D points in Openframeworks stored in the Vec3f

vector vertex;

I'm trying to get the middle point of these verticies points. My code at the moment is something like this

```
*for (int vertOne = 0; vertOne< 39; vertOne++) {

        vertex.push_back(vertices[vertOne].getMiddle(vertices[vertOne++]));  

}*
```

I want to have the vertices[vertOne] to move up through the loop like  - 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 etc.

But i want .getMiddle(vertices[vertOne++]) to move through the loop starting at 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 etc.

So i want the first array to start at 0 and the second one to start at 1 and move in pair upwards through the loop

Im new to programming so any help would be great

Thanks!

Comment: `vertex.push_back(vertices[vertOne].getMiddle(vertices[vertOne + 1]));`

Comment: It's because ```vertOne++``` modifies ```vertOne```, so your code goes up in twos.

Comment: A `std::vector` has a size. Prefer that over a magic number like 39. Be aware of that size if you use `index + 1` to access the next item. You'll either need to stop 1 before the end or handle the last item differently.

Comment: Why do you have `*` around the code? It can't compile like that.

Answer (score 0):

The postfix ++ operator increases the value stored in the variable and stores the result back in the variable. You want to increment that value but not store the result back in the variable. You can achieve this just by adding 1 (vertOne + 1).

Comment: When using this method be carefull to not run out of bounds

Comment: thank you very much for the quick response - I really appreciate it alot!